# Initializing my variable over and over agian in my recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, initialization, return-value

```
#include <stdio.h>

int _strlen_recursion(char *s);

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    n = _strlen_recursion("Corbin Coleman");
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return (0);
}

int _strlen_recursion(char *s)
{
    int count = 0;
    
    
    if( s[0] == '\0')
    {
        return (count);
    }
    else
    {
        s++;
        count++;
        _strlen_recursion(s);
        return (count);
    }

}
```

This is my code. When I run it, I get 1 as my answer. After using python tutor, I realized it's because my variable keeps being set back to 0. I've tried various ways to fix it, watched YouTube videos and looked at other questions posted online about this, yet I can't figure out how to fix it. I'm new to programming, if someone could explain what's going on and how to fix it I'd appreciated it.

The point of my code is to print out the total number of characters in the string. I cannot use the standard library or global variables.

Expected output:

```
14
```

Comment: This is not a good use of recursion - it's not scalable and can cause deep recursions that overrun the stack. So the obvious question - are you doing this for learning reasons or are you thinking this is actually the best way to achieve the required result?

Comment: as an aside, identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved in the file-scoped namespace.

Comment: learning reasons! today is my first day learning recursion. so i'm doing basic recursion problems assigned to me.

Answer (score 7):

Variable `count` is local to your function, or even to specific level of recursion. You cannot share it between levels of recursion.

You must either use global variable or pass `count` as an argument.
Personally, I would simply remove it.

Just return 0 for empty string or 1 plus length of string one letter shorter:

```
int _strlen_recursion(char *s) {
    if (s[0] == 0) return 0;
    return 1 + _strlen_recursion(s + 1);
}
```

Return 14 as expected.

Answer (score 1):

use `static` keyword there and you'll be fine
and change stuff to  `int r = count; count = 0; return r;`

Comment: ... as long as you only need to measure the length of a single string.